# Facebook: FB.apiClient TypeError: $wnd.FB.Facebook is undefined" why this error occures?

Tags: gwt, facebook

We are facing one problem with facebook.
we integrated FB in our web application, when user login through fconnect in our web application then he registered with our system(1st time only) just providing his email id.For normal user few user i/p for registration in our system

Our web-application developed in java [GWT2.0].

Problem is when FACEBOOK or normaluser  login through FB in our web-application.( 1 at a time)

when user refreshes page then FB pop window Occues with message

**"Debug: Exception while loading FB.apiClient TypeError: $wnd.FB.Facebook is undefined"**

or sometimes **$wnd.FB.Facebook.apiClient is null**  occures

we get above error[pop-up] message 3 times.

we used following script in html page 
< script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php">

In only 1 page of our web-application i.e UserHome page where we display users info .
on that page only above error message occurs

We used following GWT Code [from Gwittit] In controller class[Singleton class ]

> /**
>        * Function get called when all the data on first page get loaded.
>        * 
>        * */
>       public void notifyFinishedLoadinPage() {
>           FacebookConnect.waitUntilStatusReady(new
>   RenderAppWhenReadyCallback());
>
> ```
> }
> ```
>
> private MyLoginCallback
>   loginCallback = new MyLoginCallback();
>
> ```
> class MyLoginCallback implements LoginCallback {
>
>     public void onLogin() {
>         isFacebookSign = true;
>         fbLoggedInUserId = ApiFactory.getInstance().getLoggedInUser();
>
>         for (FacebookObserver Observer : facebookObservers) {
>             Observer.notifyFacebookLogin(true);
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> public void publishStream(final FacebookObserver fbObserver) {
>     FacebookConnect.init(FacebookConstants.FACEBOOK_API_KEY,
> ```
>
> "xd_receiver.htm", loginCallback);
>
> ```
>     FacebookConnect.requireSession(new
> ```
>
> AsyncCallback() {
>
> ```
>         public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
>             Window.alert("Require session failed: " + caught);
>             GWT.log("Require session failed: " + caught, null);
>         }
>
>         public void onSuccess(Boolean isLoggedIn) {
>             if (isLoggedIn) {
>                 for (FacebookObserver Observer :
> ```
>
> facebookObservers) {
>                           Observer.notifyPublishStream();
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>           });
>
> ```
> }
>
> public void facebookConnection() {
>     FacebookConnect.init(FacebookConstants.FACEBOOK_API_KEY,
> ```
>
> "xd_receiver.htm", loginCallback);
>   //SERVER
>           FacebookConnect.requireSession(new
>   AsyncCallback() {
>
> ```
>         public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
>             GWT.log("Require session failed: " + caught, null);
>         }
>
>         public void onSuccess(Boolean isLoggedIn) {
>             if (loginCallback != null && isLoggedIn) {
>                 loginCallback.onLogin();
>             } else {
>                 //User not logged in
>             }
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> /**
>  * Fired when we know users status
>  */
> private class RenderAppWhenReadyCallback implements
> ```
>
> AsyncCallback {
>
> ```
>     public RenderAppWhenReadyCallback() {
>         FacebookConnect.init(FacebookConstants.FACEBOOK_API_KEY,
> ```
>
> "xd_receiver.htm", loginCallback);
>   //SERVER
>           }
>
> ```
>     public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
>         Window.alert("Unable to login through Facebook: " + caught);
>     }
>
>     public void onSuccess(ConnectState result) {
>         if (result == ConnectState.connected) {
>             isFacebookSign = true;
>
>             for (FacebookObserver Observer : facebookObservers) {
>                 Observer.notifyFacebookLogin(true);
>             }
>
>             //History.newItem(HistoryConstants.USERHOME_PAGE_HISTORY_TOKEN);
>         } else {
>             //rightSideFlexTable.clearCell(0, 0);
>             //rightSideFlexTable.setWidget(0, 0,
> ```
>
> facebookPanel);
>                   isFacebookSign = false;
>
> ```
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

Now we unable to found solution to this problem.

Can any one help Us to solve this problem ASAP

Hope-for the Best Co-operation

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your problem? Are you trying to use a regular JS Facebook library from GWT? If so, which one, and what's the code look like?

Comment: @jason Hall we used following script in html page < script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php">   

Can you explain me why this error occurs ?

Comment: Can you use Firebug or Chrome's Dev Tools to check that the script is being loaded? Try using the console to call methods on `apiClient`. Are you trying to call this code from GWT? Can you post that code?

Comment: @jason hall I added GWT code for your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found solution for above Question.

Facebook (login)loading requires few time.

In Our web page we fetch fb details like fb users loggedInId ,Image,etc.
so at the time of page loading we get all values null because facebook not load properly
so we get  **$wnd.FB.Facebook.apiClient is null**   or

**Debug: Exception while loading FB.apiClient TypeError: $wnd.FB.Facebook is undefined"**

To solve this problem we write one method which calls when user refreshes page or after facebook loading done properly.

> public void notifyFacebookLogin(boolean isLogin) {
>
> Long fbLoggedInUserId = ApiFactory.getInstance().getLoggedInUser();
>
> if (fbLoggedInUserId != null) {
>
> ```
> if (globalEndUserInfo == null) {
>     globalEndUserInfo = new EndUserInfo();
>     globalEndUserInfo.setFbLoggedInUserId(fbLoggedInUserId);
>   }
> ```
>
> }
>
> // code wherever we deal with FB related object
>
> }

Now no error message display when user refreshes page or if fb takes time to loading

In this way we solve our Problem. :)